# In-code-compile in library: How to add DLL reference to component when component is located in project hosting the library?

Tags: .net, compiler-construction

I'm writing a class library (say: **lib**) that parses and compiles Razor templates. The class library will be referenced in a project (say: **proj**) that contains the raw Razor templates.

The class library references a 3d party component (say: **comp**) which I am unable (licence-wise) to package within the library. This is not a problem because the **proj** will always contain the **comp** reference.

However inside **lib** I need to add the **comp** to the referenced assemblies:

```
var outputAssemblyName = Path.GetTempPath() + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N") + ".dll";
CompilerParameters compilerParameters = new CompilerParameters(ReferencedAssemblies, outputAssemblyName);
compilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
compilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Core.dll");
compilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("3dpartycomp.dll"); //<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

The **comp** dll however isn't found when it's located in the **/bin** folder of the **proj**. Also the **proj** doesn't have a **/release** folder because it is a website.

**How do I add a reference to the 3d party component when it is located in the project *hosting* the library?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While adding reference, specify full path to your third party assemblies (like @"C:\App\bin\3rdpartycomp.dll"), as compiler only looks in framework directory (not even GAC) when a reference without path is specified. You may use Server.MapPath to get location of bin directory.

Comment: You might expect this, however the following error is thrown: Line: 0 Col: 0 Error: Metadata file 'file:\D:\local\TestSolution\TestProject\bin\3dpartycomp.dll' could not be found

Comment: Somehow file:\ is prepended when I'm getting the executing assembly path. Removing it fixed the problem, great!

Comment: @Ropstah  Can I ask you How do you strip out the "file:\" part?